# Is there a pair of prime $(p,q)$ such that $p >q>7$ and $2q-p=3$ and $p, q$ are successive?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I'm failed to find at a least one pair of primes$(p,q)$  $p >q>7$ and $2q-p=3$ with $p, q$ are successive , I think tha's impossible because we do not know more about Gaps between prime and if there is those pair it should be large , then my question how i can find that pair or to disproof it's existence ?

**Edit:**  I have added the missed condition wich is $p, q$ are successives

Comment: What about $p=31, q=17?$

Comment: Why exactly do you think that solutions should be large?

Comment: Leaving open. Notable pattern in primes.

Answer (score 1):

The key requirement is that the primes $p,q$ be sequential (that is, that there should be no prime between them).

Your assumption implies that $$q=\frac {p+3}2$$

However, a strong form of [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)  tells us that, for $n>25$, there must be a prime between $n$ and $\frac 65 n$.  Applying this to $n=\frac {p+3}2$ shows that, except for very small $p$, there must be a prime between $\frac {p+3}2$ and $p$ and from there a simple finite search shows that your desired primes do not exist.

Comment: +1 What a wonderful coincidence!

Answer (score 1):

If $p>q>7$ are succcessive primes with $2q-p=3$ then $p=2q-3$. This implies that there are no primes between $q+1$ and $2q-4$. This comes close to contradicting [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

In fact it does contradict improvements on Bertrand's postulate; the theorem at the bottom of page 180 of [this article](https://doi.org/10.3792/pja/1195570997) states that for every $n\geq9$ there is a prime $r$ such that
$$n\leq r\leq\frac{4}{3}n.$$
If $q>7$ is prime then $q+1\geq9$ so we find that there is a prime $r$ such that
$$q+1\leq r\leq\frac{4}{3}(q+1)\leq 2q-4,$$
and hence $q<r<p$. This shows that $q$ and $2q-3$ are *not* successive primes. So two successive primes $p>q>7$ never satisfy $2q-p=3$.

Comment: I think we both posted this, oddly specific, argument within seconds of each other.  Worth keeping both posts up if for no other reason than to memorialize the coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

$(p,q)=(31,17)$ works unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

Since $p, q$ are successive then you can rewrite your equation as $$2p_n-p_{n+1}=3$$
This shows that $p_{n+1}$ is almost double $p_n$ which seems to be forbidden for sufficiently large primes. This is because between $x$ and $2x$ exist many primes.
Write your equation in the form $p_{n+1}=2p_n-3$. This means that the number of primes in the interval $(x, 2x-3]$ is one (for $x=p_n$).
It is [proved here](https://doi.org/10.3792/pja/1195570997) that for $x\ge25$ there is a prime between $x$ and $\frac{6}{5}x$.
So, we have one prime between $p_n$ and $\frac{6}{5}p_n$ and one more between $\frac{6}{5}p_n$ and $\frac{6}{5}\cdot \frac{6}{5}p_n=\frac{36}{25}p_n$ if $p_n\ge 25$.
Since you have only one prime between $p_n$ and $2p_n-3$ we must have $2p_n-3<\frac{36}{25}p_n$vwhich gives $14p_n<75$ or $p_n<6$. Hence $p=2, 3$ or $5$.
The prime $5$ is the only good one to satisfy your equation.